# Cotura.Fody Not Working In JetBrains Rider EAP

Tags: c#, fody-costura, rider

I'm working on a project, and it uses a few libraries (RestSharp, Newtonsoft.Json, CsQuery) and I didn't want to use the exe with all the dlls in the same directory, so I also installed Costura.Fody, and that worked when I used Visual Studio, but now I'm using JetBrains Rider EAP, and the output exe file does not include the embedded dlls/ If I move it, It crashes saying something like "Cant load CsQuery" etc.

I'm running a 64 bit version of Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3, and Rider EAP 15.

Anyone else having thing problem/know how to fix it?

Comment: Operating System?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that with Visual studio it was clear, but I guess that they're making it for other platforms as well so I should be more clear. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Well, VS for sure runs on Windows but Rider is cross-platform ;)

Comment: Yeah, I gotchu.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug which makes Costura.Fody useless while using Rider EAP. After switching to Visual Studio 2015 Community and re-installing Costura.Fody in project and compiling - everything works fine and dll's are embedded.

Compiling with Rider EAP doesn't embed any dll's.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've noticed. I've been building my programs in Rider and then moving copy/pasting the files into my project in VS. Only solution I could find so far.