# Is it possible to embed multiple dll files (references) into final dll file using Fody.Costura?

Tags: c#, dll, fody, fody-costura

as title states:

Is it possible to embed my references (.dll files) in to my final, compiled .dll file using Fody.Costura?

I'm quite sure I did proper setup but I can't see any difference between .dll file compiled with installed Fody.Costura and without it. Also it's always the same size. I'm doing it wrong or does it work only for .exe files?

Cheers,
Jacob.

@edit
Just found this thread:
[Cotura.Fody Not Working In JetBrains Rider EAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478072/cotura-fody-not-working-in-jetbrains-rider-eap)

I'm not using Visual Studio, I'm using Rider EAP too and probably facing same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:
Yes, it's possible to embed .dll files in to final compiled .dll using Costura.Fody.

It didn't work for me because of IDE that I'm using which is "JetBrains Rider EAP" - looks like a bug which makes Costura.Fody useless. After switching to Visual Studio 2015 Community and re-installing Costura.Fody in project and compiling again - everything works fine and dll's are embedded.